# ggplot: annotation_custom aspect ratio preservation

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics

It is possible to add an image to a `ggplot` graphics by using `annotation_custom()`:

```
library("png")
my_image <- readPNG("Rlogo.png", native = TRUE)
ggplot() + theme_void() + 
  annotation_raster(my_image, xmin=-Inf, ymin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymax=Inf)
```

This scales the image according to the size of the plot.

Is there a way to preserve the aspect ratio of the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the image to automatically preserve aspect ratio under resizing, then instead of using `annotation_raster` (which adds a `geom_raster` layer), use `annotation_custom`, with `my_image` used to create a `grid::rasterGrob`

Here, I have added a frame around the entire panel so you can see how the aspect ratio of the image is preserved whatever happens to the plot dimensions:

```r
library(png)

my_image <- readPNG('D://Rlogo.png', native = TRUE)

ggplot() + 
  theme_void() + 
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(linewidth = 2, color = 'black')) +
  annotation_custom(grid::rasterGrob(my_image), 
                    xmin = -Inf, ymin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymax = Inf)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]